# 10.10 still wont load 12.04

Tags: installation, 10.10, 12.04, boot

I have an old version of Ubuntu: 10.10. My other computer died so I got an Acer Aspire One D270-1865. I deleted as much of the Microsoft crap as possible. I changed the boot up to CD-ROM with F2 and F12. It will boot, then ask for login name then password. I give the corrrect ones then it says changes are avaliable etc and has my name again except after it there appears: `AOD 270:~$` Then I'm supposed to put something there. I don't know what. I tried password, login name, etc. Nothing works. It then goes back to version 10.10. I've already down loaded the 12.04 several times thinking that it might be the problem. But still the same 10.10. What do I do?

Comment: Ubuntu is giving you a virtual console, and expecting that you interact with it by entering commands. Unless you have a command-line only Ubuntu install, this is usually because Ubuntu can't use your graphics card. Is Ubuntu installed on your computer, or are you trying to run/install it off the CD? Have Ubuntu 10.10 and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS really behaved *exactly* the same? Have you tried [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)? Have you checked the CD for defects ([this guide](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) still works)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the hard drive of your old computer in your new computer. So you're trying to boot from 12.04 live CD and and you're old 10.10 boots up? Obviously the computer did not boot from CD, it probably did not recognise the CD. Try creating a bootable USB stick with the boot media creator or unetbootin, there may probably be issues with your optical drive or the medium used for burning.

You're seeing that virtual terminal because the new system needs another graphics driver than the currently installed one. Is there a specific reason why you're using the old drive? It would be much simpler using the new drive, installing 12.04 on that and copying the files from your old home directory to the new one.